# Mongo create field with merge of 2 arrays of same collection (like Left join in relational)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mapreduce, projection

I have a collection that has 2 arrays inside. One has fewer props than other, but both are linked by prop 'Code'.

I would like to project a 3rd array that would be the merge of both, but they must be distinct. An example:

```
[
  {
    'PartnerName': "Company A - Both Complete Equal",
    'MarketExpertese1': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'Label': 'Sector 1' } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'Label': 'Sector 2' } }
    ],
    'MarketExpertese2': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'TotalDays': 1 } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'TotalDays': 1 } }
    ]
  },
    {
    'PartnerName': "Company B - 1 has more",
    'MarketExpertese1': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'Label': 'Sector 1' } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'Label': 'Sector 2' } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 3, 'Label': 'Sector 3' } }
    ],
    'MarketExpertese2': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'TotalDays': 1 } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'TotalDays': 1 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    'PartnerName': "Company C - 2 has more",
    'MarketExpertese1': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'Label': 'Sector 1' } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'Label': 'Sector 2' } }
    ],
    'MarketExpertese2': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'TotalDays': 1 } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'TotalDays': 1 } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 3, 'TotalDays': 1 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    'PartnerName': "Company D - 1 has - 2 Null",
    'MarketExpertese1': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'Label': 'Sector 1' } }
    ],
    'MarketExpertese2': null
  },
  {
    'PartnerName': "Company E - 1 null - 2 has",
    'MarketExpertese1': null,
    'MarketExpertese2': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'TotalDays': 1 } }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here on Company A both arrays have the same number of itens, so the 3rd array would be the merge, the result would be (just added prop TotalDays to array1):

```
'MarketExpertese3': [
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 1, 'Label': 'Sector 1', 'TotalDays': 10 } },
      { 'Sector': { 'Code': 2, 'Label': 'Sector 2', 'TotalDays': 20 } }
    ]
```

In this example both arrays have the same len and the same codes, but sometimes they are different. Some time one is null and other not, sometimes empty, etc...

Sometimes I will have to add TotalDays:0 when array1 has more itens the array 2. Sometimes I will have to populate prop from array 1 into array 2.

Looking arround I am lost, I don´t know if I need to unwind/group/map or unwind/reduce/group/map... I get lost when I need to verify the prop Code in both to check if I need to get array 1 and merge into 2 or or vice versa

[Here is a playgrod with the data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/soJZ3IBp7KA)

cheers

Comment: Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FIUXWtUYL9b), prop array1 into array2, really costly for your query operation, my suggestion is to do this in client side in your language.

Comment: @turivishal in your solution it working, but it only gets when both arrays have the same code. as I said, sometimes array 1 will have more items then array 2 and vice versa... on these cases, array 3 need to have these ones too...

Comment: Yes i know that and its possible vice versa, , i just sent it for review, there would be same process for otherside as well, i don't think there are other simple ways. do you really want this in mongo query? because that's why i suggested to do this in your client side language.

Comment: Yes you are right, its more costly doing all on mongo query...probably I will do in my NodeJS app... but I was wondering how to do in mogo just to study more the mongo functions.... looking them, I found a lookup functions that looks like it does the same as the left join in the relational db...do you think it would work? like unwind both arrays and  use the lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$set` check if any array id null then update to empty array [], for making clear operation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      MarketExpertese1: { $ifNull: ["$MarketExpertese1", []] },
      MarketExpertese2: { $ifNull: ["$MarketExpertese2", []] }
    }
  },
```

- Prepare third array `MarketExpertese3`, iterate loop using `$map` of array `MarketExpertese2` and sync with `MarketExpertese1`, `$reduce` to iterate loop of `MarketExpertese1` and get matching `Sector` object and merge with `MarketExpertese2`'s object using `$mergeObjects`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      MarketExpertese3: {
        $map: {
          input: "$MarketExpertese2",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            Sector: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$m.Sector",
                {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$MarketExpertese1",
                    initialValue: {},
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$m.Sector.Code", "$$this.Sector.Code"] },
                        "$$this.Sector",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- Now we need to sync `MarketExpertese1` array to `MarketExpertese3` newly prepared array,
- `$map` to iterate loop of `MarketExpertese1` array and check of any status is new then return otherwise return null, `$filter` to remove null from array, concat return array with `MarketExpertese3` using `$concatArrays`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      MarketExpertese3: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$MarketExpertese3",
          {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$MarketExpertese1",
                  as: "m",
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$MarketExpertese2",
                              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.Sector.Code", "$$m.Sector.Code"] }
                            }
                          },
                          []
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$m",
                      "$$REMOVE"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              cond: { $ne: ["$$this", null] }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6d9uavQ9_mx)

Comment: Almost work... when array1 and 2 have the same itens work fine, but when they are different, the final result is missing some props... Here I have a real example, on my data the Array1 is MarketExpertises and Array2 is Statistics.MarketEpertese. On the result comes 4 itens, the 1st two are merged OK and the last 2 are missing TotalYears. I guess I have just to MAP the final result and check if the prop TotalYears exists, if not, a AddToSet would fix, is that correct? https://mongoplayground.net/p/hgt2tAYfmwy

Comment: Here is the correct playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/RxLlKARXHfE